# jquery ajax autocomplete not sure how to make it work

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use jquery ajax autocomplete extender for the first time, it's not working out for me so far.  Please point out errors and suggestions to make this work.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{
                $.support.cors=true;
        $('#firstName').autocomplete({

                alert('HEY');
                minLength:2,
                source: function( request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'http://MyServer/MyService/api/StaffSearch/GetStaffByFirstName'
                    data: {'term': request.term},
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert('success in autocomplete');
                        response(data);
                    },
                    error: function(msg) {
                        alert('error in autocomplete');
                    }
                })
        },

        })//end autocomplete

});
    </script>


    <div>
        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName">
    </div>
```

Comment: What happens? What doesn't happen? What's in the JS console? Do you have a working fiddle? These kinds of things are often trivial to debug. Answering the questions I just asked (except the last) are often enough.

Comment: if you can't figure it out, that's all you have to say.....

Comment: Note: The `contentType` parameter is the `Content-type` header ***sent to*** the server in the ***request***.  It is *not* the `Content-type` of the response.  That's the job of `dataType` (and/or your server).  Get rid of the `contentType` parameter here, it may be breaking your request.

Comment: So, what do you mean by "not working"?  What happens when you type into the textbox?  Try to look at the request in the dev tools.  Do you see the request?  The response?  Do you see any on your `alert`s?  What happens if you put `console.log(data)` inside the `success` function?

Comment: @user1220099 If you can't ask a complete question and provide information that's trivial to access, what good will an answer do you? There's a *reason* you open up the JS console and look for errors. It's called debugging. Consider trying it; even if you *can't* figure it out from that, the information you provide may help somebody *else* figure it out. Don't make us do *all* your work, *help* us help you. And I'd consider ratcheting down the notion that someone that *doesn't* help is doing so because they *can't*, and instead look inward.

Comment: I see you're using `$.support.cors=true;`.  Are you trying to make a cross-domain request here?  If so, is your server sending the right headers?

Comment: @user1220099: Just from this code, *no one* can figure it out; we have no idea what's happening.  You need to give more details, we're not here to debug your code for you, we're here to help when you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `$` in `.ajax({`